# Storing Key-Value pairs in VBA macro

Tags: vba, outlook

The final stage of a long macro that I've written in outlook is to route an email to the appropriate person, depending on all of the things that the macro has found out. I've done this before using an excel sheet and a vlookup of the "Key" value - but in this case the key-value pairs will be static, and so excel feels like overkill, and will slow things down.

Both the key and value will be strings, less than 50 characters each most likely, but there will probably be around 1500 pairs. Would compiling it into some kind of DLL or something be best?

Comment: Have a look at the `Scripting.Dictionary` object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dictionary-object

Comment: surely creating a 1500 pair dictionary with 1500 lines of code every time the macro runs would be a bit on the slow side?

Comment: unless I've got the wrong end of the stick; initialising the dictionary: `d.Add "a", "Athens"` `d.Add "b", "Belgrade"` etc.

Comment: No, that's how you add to it. The dictionary isn't part of the standard VBA library, it's located in the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library. Therefore you either have to add a reference to the library, or create the object using `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`. Plenty of resources on the internet to see how it works and most importantly what it used for. Maybe a simple built-in Collection might fit your needs.

Comment: @MartinKS - see this link as well, you can loop over the dictionary easily - https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Comment: OK, I can see how to use the dictionary, and that it's exactly what I need for the quick lookup of routes. I currently have a list of 1500 key-pair values though, what's the best way of getting them into the macro ready for each time it runs?

Comment: @MartinKS: Two ways jump to mind immediately: (1) store them in a workbook that is processed by the macro on startup; or (2) Write code to write an initialization routine from wherever you have the list stored now
. BTW: the VBA Collection object ***is a key-value dictionary*** at its core.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - I would imagine a csv file is a faster option than starting a copy of excel, so I'll test that route.

Comment: @MartinKS: Note that the default application associated with the extension ".csv" is often EXCEL.exe. ;-)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - I was just going to use a plain `Open csvFilePath For Input As #FileNum` but thanks for reminding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way is to stick all the values into a text file with the key and value separated by a space (or other suitable character if there are spaces in the key or value) and then add them into the dictionary.  On my 300MHz P3, this takes less than a second to run.

```
Dim objDict As Object, objFSO As Object, objFile As Object
Dim strLine As String, strs As Variant

Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, forReading)
For ii = 1 To 1500
    strs = Split(objFile.ReadLine(), " ")
    objDict.Add strs(0), strs(1)
Next
objFile.Close
```

Comment: Thanks - this is the answer that was reached in the comments